# DB2 SQL for Random and Limit

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table Test_Person and Test_Person_Details

```
Test_Person
ID (PrimaryKey)
STATUS "NEW/OLD"

Test_Person_Details
ID (FK)
NAME
AGE
DESC
...
```

I have to get randomly 10 Names for a given ID WHERE STATUS is 'NEW'..What would be the query in DB2?

Answer (score 2):

This is a slow way:

```
select pd.name
from (select p.*
      from test_person p
      order by rand()
      fetch first 10 rows only
     ) p join
     test_person_details pd
     on p.id = pd.id;
```

If your table has more than 1000 rows, you can make it more efficient by doing:

```
select pd.name
from (select p.*
      from test_person p tablesample bernoulli(1)
      order by rand()
      fetch first 10 rows only
     ) p join
     test_person_details pd
     on p.id = pd.id;
```

Comment: The 2nd query may be specific to LUW.